# 2 loading icon spinning jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 loading icon using inline style, I use the first icon as loading webpage icon after I login and the second loading icon when i click button post it will show loading icon and after that it will show the comment. I set them display as none for style and then using jquery i show them by calling the id but i dont know how to see them in localhost in apache server and also how to set them default in online? If i click the post button it will also loading the whole webpage with the message sample HELLO WORLD, HI WORLD so that's why i cant see the loading icon

[image: 2 Loading icon]

css

```
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 16px solid blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="loadingwindow" class="loader" style="display: none;"> 
       </div>

      <div id="container">

      <form  id="formsubmitcomment">
            <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php 
                 echo $user_id?>">
            <textarea name="post" id="post" style="resize: none"></textarea>

              <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
       </form>


      <div id="commentload" class="loader" style="display: none;">

         </div>
      <div id="postcomment">

          </div>

     </body>
</html>
```

jquery

```
$(window).ready(function(){
   $("#loadingwindow").ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).css("display", "block");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
            });

  $("#loadingwindow").ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
            });
 });


$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#submit").click(function (){
         $.post("postcomment.php", $("#formsubmitcomment").serialize(), 
          function(){
              $("#commentload").css("display: block");
                               });         
                               });

    $("#postcomment").load("showpostcomment.php", function(){

                                 }); 
  });
```

php showpostcomment.php

```
  session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="w3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require './database.php';
       $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
      $showpostcomment = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  $sql = "SELECT user_id, post_comment from postcomment WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY postcomment_id DESC";
      mysqli_stmt_prepare($showpostcomment, $sql);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($showpostcomment, "i", $user_id);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($showpostcomment);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($showpostcomment, $user_id, $post_comment);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($showpostcomment);

      while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($showpostcomment)) {
          echo "<div class='w3-panel w3-white'>";
        echo "<p>$post_comment </p>";   
        echo "</div>";
      } 




        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i click the post it will load the whole page

Comment: Firstly I suggest you to use a single loader element and use it for all purposes since it has the same image. Make functions like showLoader and hideLoader, then you should make the request to showpostcomment.php only into the callback of the insert, otherwise it will be called immediately also if the insert hasn't finished yet. Last thing, you are sending all html and head headers in your php file, but then the content is placed inside a div, it is not good

Comment: for example if the user have low internet connection, it will automatic will stop the loading icon if it is fully loaded the page?

Comment: what is the default number hide and show or leave it as blank?

Comment: Example for hideLoader: `$("#loaderId").css("display", "none");
            $("#loaderId").fadeOut("slow");` you can call show before make the AJAX requests, and hide when it is completed (into the callback)

Comment: i must leave all html elements and only left is inside the php code in the showpostcomment.php